# Loop to insert row AND then select first cell of that row in VBA

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I have a column with a list of either 't/n' or 's/n' which have been sorted. I also have a script that will loop through each cell, checking for when 't/n' switches to 's/n' (t/n is always sorted first), and then inserts three blank rows.

The issue is, after the rows have been inserted, I want to select the cell just above the newly separated (thanks to new rows) 's/n' data - this is because I'll then call another script that will pull in a list of headers (that will sit above the 's/n' data)

So far I have:

```
Sub modTestTemplate()

Dim rngTestTemplate As Range
Set rngTestTemplate = Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(4, 0)
rngTestTemplate.Select

Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim CurrentRow As Integer
LastRow = rngTestTemplate.End(xlDown).Row
CurrentRow = 1

Do While CurrentRow <= LastRow

    If Range("B" & CurrentRow).Value = "s/n" Then
        Range("B" & CurrentRow).EntireRow.Resize(3).Insert xlUp
        LastRow = LastRow + 1
        CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
        Exit Do
    End If

    CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1 ' this sets the cell back to the start for the loop

Loop

'when the loop is done I'm wanting to select the cell just above 's/n' as the data needs headers

End Sub
```

Comment: Just add `Range("B" & CurrentRow).Select` after your insert line (not that selecting generally achieves anything).

Comment: Great thank you! Yeah not ideal but quick and easy work around - does the job. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

`Range("B" & CurrentRow).Select` does the job - as pointed out by SJR.